# Youtube api - pageToken

Tags: javascript, api, youtube

Im new to coding, so if you can keep that in mind when explaining. Struggling with the Youtube pageToken & nextPageToken. I cannot figure out how to call more results once I have my first group. I see the nextPageToken code, but confused on how to use it to get the next set.

The YT api doc page says I need a string in the nextPageToken, but what does it have to say & how do I call it?

Sorry if Im unclear, like I said, Im new & learning how to explain my issues.

Comment: What have you got so far and what have you tried?

Comment: Hello @NewToJS, here is what I did so far. http://codepen.io/lawrenceiii/pen/YGZrrp I finally got it to load the nextPage, but it only works once. Odd. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found your the issue and managed to fix it.

You never pass the `pgToken` when calling `getNextVids()` So for some reason it isn't updating.

**Swap:**

```
function getNextVids(vidSearch, pgToken){
```

**For:**

```
function getNextVids(vidSearch){
```

and all should work fine.

Also you don't need the `onclick` attribute on your `next` button as you have jQuery dealing with that event.

```
<button class='next'>Next page</button>
```

> [**CodePen Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jrxXam)

I hope this helps you.

Happy Coding!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Im still new & trying to practice using these API's. Thanks again.

Comment: @LCiii You are very welcome! I had worked with youtube's API some time ago so I still remember the most part of it, anymore problems just let me know and I will be happy to help you the best I can.